# SSRS report - Hide charts and reuse their space

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report with two charts and a table underneath.

I want to show charts or a table conditionally. Have no problem with that but if I hide upper objects their space is not used.

I am putting charts and table into another table with two rows assuming I can hide/show these rows. But as soon as I moved charts into this table it's not working anymore. Runtime complains about series or something. Any idea what direction to take to get what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put chart inside table row.

Please try below steps: 
1 Keep Chart and Table both separate place.
2 Write expression for hide and show chart and table based on your condition.
3 Then put chart on top of table or table of chart in design view.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. Nice to have same opinion from a  fellow developer! Thanks.